# Marshal Unmanaged struct to C# (Unity's mono)

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, mono, marshalling

I am trying to understand what is the best way to update structure passed from C# to C++ to modify. Following code shows my intentions.
I have c++ side structure as below:

```
    // data.cpp
    struct Pos {
     int x;
     int y;
    }

    struct PointInfo {
     int count;
     Pos positions[10];   // Ideally I wanted vector<Pos> 
    }


    // data.cs
    [StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    [System.Serializable]
    public struct Pos {
     int X;
     int Y;
    }

    [StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    [System.Serializable]
    public struct PositionInfo {
     int count;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 10)]
     public Pos positions;
   }


   // In C# side only
   public PositionInfo pInfo = new PositionInfo();
   pInfo.positions = new Pos[10];


  // In C# Interop function
  [DllImport (dllName)]
  private static extern void GetPositions(ref PositionInfo pInfo);
```

This method in implemented in c++ side (unmanaged plugin) as:

```
extern "C" void INTERFACE_EXPORT
    GetPositions(PositionInfo* pinfo)
{
   pinfo.count = 3;
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    pinfo.pos[i].x = i*2;
    pinfo.pos[i].y = i*4;
   }
}
```

This does not work. If I replace Pos with Int then it works. I am trying to understand what is the best way to pass above structure from C# to be filled by C++ plugin.